# How to implement fragment for two component in angular

Tags: angular

I have hyperlinks in sidebar component and Tables in main component. I want to move or scroll corresponding  table for hyper click events .Can anybody suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Javascript DOM to implement this in my project

```
sideNavScroll(id: string) {
        document.querySelector('#' + id).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p6itee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: am use the above code am getting  error cannor read property sccrollIntoView of undefined

Comment: That means there's no `HTMLElement` with `id`. First, assign id's to all the `HTMLElements` you have hyperlink in sidenav. and then pass the respective id to this function

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p6itee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts